# Linker errors with cgo cross-compiling to Windows with mingw32

Tags: mingw-w64, cgo

I'm working on a small Cgo service.  We're targeting Linux deployment, but I want to have a Windows executable for local testing.  The Linux build completes and executes, but the Windows cross-compile gets some linker errors that I don't understand.  I could use some hints on how to move forward from this:

```
CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=windows GOARCH=amd64 go build -o target/dist/windows-amd64
# voltagems/voltagefuncs
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: $WORK/b122/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_88b59ed285ae_Cfunc_VeCreateFPE':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:55: undefined reference to `__imp_VeCreateFPE'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: $WORK/b122/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_88b59ed285ae_Cfunc_VeCreateLibCtx':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:75: undefined reference to `__imp_VeCreateLibCtx'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: $WORK/b122/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_88b59ed285ae_Cmacro_VeFPEParamsDefaults':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:92: undefined reference to `__imp_VeFPEParamsDefaults_v3'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: $WORK/b122/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_88b59ed285ae_Cfunc_VeGetErrorDetails':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:110: undefined reference to `__imp_VeGetErrorDetails'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: $WORK/b122/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_88b59ed285ae_Cfunc_VeGetVersion':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:127: undefined reference to `__imp_VeGetVersion'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: $WORK/b122/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_88b59ed285ae_Cmacro_VeLibCtxParamsDefaults':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:144: undefined reference to `__imp_VeLibCtxParamsDefaults_v3'
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-ld: $WORK/b122/_x002.o: in function `_cgo_88b59ed285ae_Cfunc_VeProtect':
/tmp/go-build/cgo-gcc-prolog:164: undefined reference to `__imp_VeProtect'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:3: build] Error 2
```

Some of these symbols are somewhat familiar.  The "VeProtect" and similar functions are provided by a library I link with, and those functions are all called from my cgo module.

**Update**:

If it helps, here is the top of the cgo header from the one cgo source file:

```
/*
#cgo CFLAGS: -g -Wall -I${SRCDIR}/../include/v6.21.0
#cgo linux LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/../lib/linux/v6.21.0 -lvibesimple -lvibecrypto -lvibeictk -lvibeserver
#cgo windows LDFLAGS: -L${SRCDIR}/../lib/windows/v6.21.0 -lvibesimple -lvibecrypto -lvibeictk -lvibeserver
```

and ${SRCDIR}../lib/windows/v6.21.0 contains these files (note that the source file is one subdirectory down from the root):

> ./        ssleay32.lib*    vibelocaltest.lib*  vibesimple.lib*
> ../     vibecrypto.lib*  vibeserver.lib*
> libcurl_a.lib*  vibeictk.lib*    vibesimpledyn.dll*
> libeay32.lib*   vibe.lib*    vibesimpledyn.lib*

**Update**:

I wondered if I could simply search through all the symbols in those libraries, looking for "__imp_VeCreateFPE".  I used "x86_64-w64-mingw32-nm" for this, and I found that symbol in "vibesimpledyn.lib".  I'm not certain what the relationship is between "vibesimpledyn.lib" and ""vibesimpledyn.dll".  I added "-lvibesimpledyn" to the linker flags (in addition to "-lvibesimple"), and that removed all of these linker errors, replacing them with some that are even more perplexing:

```
voltagefuncs/voltagefuncs.go:109:37: cannot use _Ctype_ulong(_Ciconst_sizeof_char * len(data)) (type _Ctype_ulong) as type _Ctype_ulonglong in argument to _Cfunc__CMalloc
voltagefuncs/voltagefuncs.go:127:32: cannot use _Ctype_ulong(_Ciconst_sizeof_char * BufSize) (type _Ctype_ulong) as type _Ctype_ulonglong in argument to _Cfunc__CMalloc
```

The first of the referenced lines is this:

```
plaintextBuffer := C.malloc(C.ulong(C.sizeof_char * len(data)))
```

Just so it's clear, the Linux version compiles and links fine, and executes this line without issue.

At this point, I don't know whether this is an issue with the vendor libraries I'm using, Cgo, or mingw32.

Comment: Are you sure you're trying to link against the libraries for the correct platform?

Comment: I see no evidence of that. I'll provide more info about the cgo file and the directory structure.

Comment: Have you tried static libraries?
On Windows shared libraries need to have their symbols exported, en applications using those shared libraries need to import those symbols (`__declspec(dllexport)` / `__declspec(dllimport)`).

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Recently, I solved something about cross-compile from amd64 to arch64, maybe we can talk about this if you need.

Comment: No, I didn't solve that problem. The vendor of the library confirmed that they don't support cross-compiling to Windows unless vscode is used. I didn't have a strong need for it, so I gave up on that.